# Redis keyspace notification limits

Tags: redis

I have around 10-15 web servers access to another service that can't handle large amounts of requests. I'm currently using Redis to cache the upstream response.

But there's a case if all servers request the same content that is not cached at the same time. It will generate 15 concurrent requests. It could be a big amount to our upstream service if there are 100 uncached contents that have been requested concurrently.

I am thinking to use `set keyt placeholder NX EX` to reserve the right to send the request for a single server and the other servers just wait for the response.

Now I have 2 options for the waiting logic

1. get the key every certain time like 50ms till the key has been updated or expired.
2. Use Redis keyspace notification on that key.

But I'm not sure if the Redis keyspace notification can handle a large number of keys. We have 200k keys right now.

Also, I'm not sure if it's overkill to wait for a very short period, The latency is normally around 50-100 ms. Maximum 30 seconds and our request will timeout.